# Finding the source of CoW page faults on OS X

Tags: memory, dtrace

I'm trying to find the source of CoW page faults in some C code on OS X.  I would like to use the [vminfo DTrace provider](http://dtrace.org/guide/chp-vminfo.html), but `vminfo` isn't available on OS X.  On Linux, I can use SystemTap to print a stack trace on a CoW fault.  Is there a way to do this on OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to disable dtrace SIP protection.

See my similar [answer over in apple.stackexchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/208763/2191) for disabling dtrace protection in SIP.

I've got SIP enabled without dtrace, and have access to vminfo.

```
# uname -a
Darwin Phoenix.local 15.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.4.0: Fri Feb 26 22:08:05 PST 2016; root:xnu-3248.40.184~3/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
# dtrace -n 'vminfo:::cow_fault {trace(probefunc)}'     
dtrace: description 'vminfo:::cow_fault ' matched 2 probes
CPU     ID                    FUNCTION:NAME
  0   1182 vm_page_validate_cs_mapped_chunk:cow_fault   vm_page_validate_cs_mapped_chunk 
  0   1182 vm_page_validate_cs_mapped_chunk:cow_fault   vm_page_validate_cs_mapped_chunk 
  0   1182 vm_page_validate_cs_mapped_chunk:cow_fault   vm_page_validate_cs_mapped_chunk
```